# The Proc behave different in different scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and start learning ruby, and i came to this proc return concept where i completely confused how the proc is returning differently.

I am attaching my code here for the reference.
I did google search too but couldn't get my answer if anyone could help please.

```
def call_proc
    puts "Before proc"
    my_proc = Proc.new { return 2 }
    my_proc.call
    puts "After proc"
  end

  def proc_call
    def inside_call
        my_proc = Proc.new {return 4}
    end
    proc = inside_call
    proc.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the difference in those 2 pieces of code ... However it all appears to be working the way it is supposed to. `Proc`s work the same way no matter how you call them.

see: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-ruby/modules/learn-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas-u/cheatsheet
and
https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/#Lambdas_vs_Procs

Your code (and my output):

```
def call_proc
  my_proc = Proc.new { return 2 }

  puts "Before proc"
  my_proc.call
puts "After proc"
end

def proc_call
  def inside_call
    my_proc = Proc.new {return 4}
  end
  proc = Proc.new {return 4}

  puts "Before proc"
  proc.call
  puts "After proc"
end
```

Output:

```
2.7.2 :112 > call_proc
Before proc
 => 2
2.7.2 :113 > proc_call
Before proc
 => 4
2.7.2 :114 >
```

In comparison, where you want to carry on after your `Proc`, you might be better off performing a `Lambda`:

```
def call_lambda
  my_lambda = -> { return 17 }

  puts "Before lambda"
  puts my_lambda.call
  puts "After lambda"
end
```

(note the `puts` before the call, and the return value of `nil`)

```
2.7.2 :122 > call_lambda
Before lambda
17
After lambda
 => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are no nested methods in Ruby. The 2nd part of your code is equivalent to:

```
def inside_call
  Proc.new { return 4 }
end

def proc_call
  proc = inside_call
  proc.call
end
```

Calling `proc_call` (still) results in a `LocalJumpError`. This is because `return` within a proc will always attempt to return from the method the proc was defined in (i.e. from `inside_call`). From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Lambda+and+non-lambda+semantics):

> - In non-lambda procs, `return` means exit from embracing method (and will throw `LocalJumpError` if invoked outside the method);